# Show git branch in file explorer

Tags: linux, git, branch

Is there any way I can show the current git branch of the directory in my file explorer?

I am using `nemo` on Linux Mint.

I know there are ways to show this up on terminal, but can it happen in a file explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are many tools available which provides GUI for GIT,

Some popular [Graphical Interfaces with it's supportive OS](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools#Graphical_Interfaces)

- [gitk](http://gitk.sourceforge.net/) - graphical history browser, in Tcl/Tk, distributed with Git
  (usually in gitk package)
- [GitForce](https://sites.google.com/site/gitforcetool/home) Git tool with Graphical user interface, available under GNU
  GPL license
- [git-cola](http://cola.tuxfamily.org/) - uses PyQt4

There is also [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/), it is very user friendly. (Not free for commercial use)

You can also install [git-gui](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gui.html) from terminal by typing

```
sudo apt-get install git-gui
```

Comment: Will I be able to use them as how i manage file explorer too?

Comment: Yes you can use it in the same way.

Comment: I just added few of the GUI which I know, many others are there you can also look for these even.

Answer (score 1):

File explorer has nothing to do with Git.

In the terminal you use scripts for displaying branch name & commands (autocomplete)

[git-completion.bash](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) or
[add-git-branch-name-to-terminal-prompt](https://github.com/mfitzp/martinfitzpatrick.name/blob/master/content/computing/add-git-branch-name-to-terminal-prompt-mac.md)

Comment: > `File system has nothing to do with Git.`
How about the presence of .git in the directory?

Comment: the file `.git/HEAD` contains the actual branch

Comment: sorry, i meant file explorer not file system.
In the command prompt you can display many things like the branch name, indication if the working directory is dirty or not and more, but file explorer is a third party application so as far as i know there is no such an option.